# Why isn't my databinding working?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Trying out databinding for the first time, but something isn't working. I'm trying to populate a combobox with the list of items in this database column. My dataset ds shows that it has stuff in it (the debugger shows it has a count of about 1500, the number of items that should be in there) and if I use the same connection string with a reader, I can print out all of the things that should be appearing in the combobox. Though the combobox is coming up empty, any ideas?

```
<ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="24,318,0,0" Name="comboBox2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="190" IsEditable="True" >
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding clt}" Width="100" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
```

And now the C#

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        string con_string = "user id=sql;password=pass;Server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,xxxx;Database=db;Trusted_Connection=False;connection timeout=15";
        string command_string = "SELECT clt FROM Client";
        SqlConnection sql_con = new SqlConnection(con_string);

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(command_string, sql_con);
            SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter();
            sqlDa.SelectCommand = command;
            sqlDa.Fill(ds);
            comboBox2.DataContext = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
```

All of the code executes without any exceptions.

Comment: Try out `combobox2.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView`, also ensure that binding which comes to each item has `clt` proeprty, basically try out following binding on textbox and say us what is displayed `Text="{Binding}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either add `ItemsSource="{Binding}"` in the XAML declaration of your combobox (prefered way)

Or do `comboBox2.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;` (quite goofy, but it does work)

That said, please note that this is not the best practice. You should have a ViewModel that holds the data specific for a view, and its logic through commands.

That ViewModel needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` if you're gonna bind against it. Typically, you'd have an ObservableCollection in that ViewModel, and you'd fill it with the result from your query. Then you'd bind on it.

Comment: Thanks, I'd managed to figure out that I needed the ItemsSource="{Binding}" though I think you're right about that not being a good way to do it since what I've selected always appears in the selected area of the combobox as something like System.Collections... etc (an annoyance is that I can't run this and be online at the same time since the SQL server is on a not internet connected intranet). I'm unfamiliar with ViewModel, so I guess that means more reading for me

Comment: Google about the MVVM pattern, it's been tutorialized a ridiculous amount of times ;)

Answer (score 0):

Write this code:-

```
    SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(command_string,sql_con);
        sqlDa.Fill(ds);

        comboBox2.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        comboBox2.DisplayMember = "clt";
```

This will display result.

Comment: It is a WPF question, not winforms. Your code won't even compile (DataSource does not exist on a WPF ComboBox)